# .htaccess on LAMP

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, lamp

I've built a test project on Codeigniter on my mac (using MAMP), and am now trying to migrate it to my Linux machine (ubuntu, LAMP), to do some tesing.

Apparently, it doesn't read the .htaccess file, since the URLs don't work (get 404) if the index.php bit is missing (on the mac it worked just fine). Should the syntax of the .htaccess file be different on LAMP and on MAMP?
This is the syntax I'm using now:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|uploads|media|myResources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I've read somewhere that you should restart the server after editing .htaccess. Problem is, I don't know how to do it on the Linux machine.

Comment: You don't need to restart anything when editing `.htaccess`, only apache configuration files. Try removing `?` character from the third line

Comment: @Vlakarados the first hint is right, but the suggestion to remove `?` doesn't have any sense

Comment: Yes it has plenty sense, I have struggled myself with this once after uploading the project to production server. I can't say why it happens, but I had no problems with my .htaccess on windows, but had to remove the `?` on centos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` rules are ignored because of [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) settings. You probably want to set

```
AllowOverride All
```

This settings belongs to `httpd.conf` or `apache.conf` and yes, you need to restart the apache server for this change to take effect. Later you can modify `.htaccess` w/o server restart.

Example configuration (part of my template for new virtual host):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # ...other configuration
  <Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, Kamil. I located those two files but couldn't see where should I put this setting.  
`/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` was an empty file (is that OK?), and in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` I didn't find a line referring to AllowOverride. Do I just add this line anywhere?

Comment: Empty `httpd.conf` is completely OK (have the same on my `Debian` instalaltions)... you can place the `AllowOverride All` into your `apache.conf` to make it global or in `VirtualHost` for specific virtualhost... in both cases place it inside the `Directory`... see my updated answer

Comment: Just came back to tell the world I finally made it, when I saw your edit here. (-:  
The relevant file in my case turned out to be `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. Thanks for your help, Kamil!